# Compilation error "reference to 'SerialUSB' is ambiguous" | on Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I get this error when compiling a simple program on a Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense (using a Mac). The sketch makes use of a library provided by Edge Impulse that uses "Arduino.h".

```
../Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/mbed/1.1.6/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:128:16: error: reference to 'SerialUSB' is ambiguous
 #define Serial SerialUSB
```

I have never seen this error before. What is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the sample problem and tried a lot to fix this.
I think the problem is at the version for the arduino nano 33 ble package.
Try downgrading the package for the arduino nano 33 ble to 1.1.4.

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a change in naming in the Arduino Core for the Nano 33 BLE Sense (some more background: https://github.com/edgeimpulse/edgeimpulse/issues/927). Will be patched later today, just re-export your project to a new Arduino library and this will include the latest changes.